# Restrict types with generic function

Tags: go, generics

Currently I have a type like this:

```golang
package hello

type object map[string]any

func add[T any](obj object, key string, val T) {
   switch value := obj[key].(type) {
   case nil:
      obj[key] = val
   case T:
      obj[key] = []T{value, val}
   case []T:
      obj[key] = append(value, val)
   }
}
```

which I use to store different types of numbers. I was thinking about
restricting the allowed types, like this:

```golang
package hello

type number interface {
   isNumber()
}

type Int32 int32
func (Int32) isNumber(){}

type Float32 float32
func (Float32) isNumber(){}

type object map[string]number
```

but I am not sure how to implement my add function as before. I tried the same
function, but I get this:

```
cannot use val (variable of type T constrained by any) as type number in assignment:
   T does not implement number (missing isNumber method)
```

so then I changed the signature to:

```golang
func add[T number](obj object, key string, val T)
```

but I get another error:

```
cannot use []T{…} (value of type []T) as type number in assignment:
   []T does not implement number (missing isNumber method)
```

is it possible to do something like what I am trying to do?

Comment: the conceptual flaw of your second attempt, which is also reflected in the error message, is that `[]T` is not a number. It's a *slice of* numbers. It's also an unnamed type, so it'll never implement the `number` interface. Also consider that switching on `T` means that subsequent calls to `add` where the key is the same but the value has a different base type (`int32` vs `float32`) would silently do nothing. If you really want to store <element> or a slice thereof in the same map, `any` might be just fine.

Comment: Then a better approach might be to parametrize `object` in `T` and declare `add` as method, so that at least it preserves type consistency of the map values. Like this: https://go.dev/play/p/6-c2HG2eGuR But actually, the map values could simply be slices, and you'd handle the cases where they hold zero, one or 2+ items, otherwise you'd basically have to type switch every time you read from the map

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding this to the code in the question, seems to work:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

type numbers[T any] []T
func (numbers[T]) isNumber(){}

func add[T number](obj object, key string, val T) {
   switch value := obj[key].(type) {
   case nil:
      obj[key] = val
   case T:
      obj[key] = numbers[T]{value, val}
   case numbers[T]:
      obj[key] = append(value, val)
   }
}

func main() {
   obj := object{"alfa": Int32(1), "bravo": Float32(1)}
   add(obj, "bravo", Float32(2))
   add(obj, "charlie", Int32(1))
   fmt.Println(obj) // map[alfa:1 bravo:[1 2] charlie:1]
}
```

If anyone has others options, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use type constraints

```golang
type number interface {
~int32 | ~float32
}
```

Instead create such Float or Int new types